i m trying to update data with updateForm async action but the data wont update
I m using Redux/Toolkit and
here is my put method from the api:
and here is my fetchForms and updateForm actions and reducers
and in fetchForms action without respond in return data.respond i can't get my data
i think the fetchForms and the updateForm are incompatable somehow
after the update button is trigered the state is showing me success
//this is my put method in the api
    router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const result = await data.updateOne(
          { _id: req.params.id },
          { $set: { ...req.body } }
        );
        res.send("form updated");
      } catch (error) {
        res.send("cannot update form");
      }
    });
//and here is my fetchForms and updateForm actions and reducers
export const fetchForms = createAsyncThunk('data/fetchAll', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/autoroute/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.respond;
});
export const updateForm = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/update',
  async ({ dataId, updatedData }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/autoroute/${dataId}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedData),
      });
      const updatedDataFromServer = await response.text();
      return updatedDataFromServer;
  }
);


const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchForms.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.data = action.payload; 
      })
      .addCase(updateForm.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.data = state.data.map(form =>
          form._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : form
        );
      })
  },
});```


Is the NodeJs code working correctly, because there is a path mismatch

i tested the code of put method with postman. its working correctly

i get Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/autoroute/undefined", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers(2), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false } in the log of the response in the updateForm
